# Error while attempting to generate library

Tags: nrwl, nrwl-nx

I upgraded from @angular/cli": "^6.0.8" to @angular/cli": "^6.1.0".
I also upgraded to

```
@nrwl/schematics": "^6.1.1"
```

Now when I attempt to generate a libarary with the command,

```
ng g lib shared-feature-store --prefix=medsoft --tags=shared,experimental
```

...I am recieving the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/route-utils'
Error: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/route-utils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (J:\workspace\medsoft\node_modules\@nrwl\schematics\src\collection\library\index.js:13:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

My previous version ran fine.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Cheers

Comment: @FatehMohamed >> the next version of nx 6.2 will be compatible with @angular/cli 5.1. Do you mean @angular/cli 6.1 instead of @angular/cli 5.1?

Comment: Yes sorry with 6.1 :)

Comment: downgrade to angular/cli 6.0, the next version of nx 6.2 will be compatible with @angular/cli 6.1

Comment: Try now! https://blog.nrwl.io/nrwl-nx-6-2-angular-6-1-and-better-state-management-e139da2cd074

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct version of `@schematics/angular`, be careful with the versions of your node dependencies.